# Homomorphism from U(30) to U(30) with a given kernel

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Find a homomorphism $f$ from $U(30)$ to $U(30)$ with kernel $\{1,11\}$ and $f(7)=7$.

I know $f(1)=1$ and $f(7)=7$, but not sure where to go from there.

Comment: What do you mean by $U(30)$? Is this $U(\mathbb Z_{30})$, the group of units of $\mathbb Z_{30}$?

Answer (score 2):

Note $\mathbb Z/30 = \mathbb Z/2 \times \mathbb Z/3 \times \mathbb Z/5$ so $U(30) = U(2) \times U(3) \times U(5) = \mathbb Z/2 \times \mathbb Z/4$ has two generators.  Multiplicatively, $7$ has order $4$, it generates the subgroup $\{1, 7, 19, 13\}$.  We can take $11$ as the second generator.  So now you're looking for a homomorphism
$$\mathbb Z/2 \times \mathbb Z/4 \to \mathbb Z/2 \times \mathbb Z/4$$
that kills the $\mathbb Z/2$ factor.  So take $(a, b) \mapsto (0, b)$.  Your homomorphism is $11^a7^b \mapsto 7^b$.