# Find a homomorphism $\phi$ from $U(30)$ to $U(30)$ such that $\ker(\phi) = \{1,11\}$ and $\phi(7) = 7$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

Find a homomorphism $\phi$ from $U(30)$ to $U(30)$ such that $\ker(\phi) = \{1,11\}$ and $\phi(7) = 7$.

Note: I have seen this [Homomorphism from U(30) to U(30) with a given kernel](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/377924/homomorphism-from-u30-to-u30-with-a-given-kernel) but I have more general questions about the First Isomorphism Theorem that I would like to address. This answer also feels case specific in that it uses the generators, and I am more interested in the general process.

Note 2: We have not covered rings, only groups.

I am having some confusion with the First Isomorphism Theorem, and I want to confirm/deny how I am supposed to interpret this. The statement given in the book is:

Let $\phi$ be a homomorphism from $G$ to $\bar{G}$. Then the mapping from $\frac{G}{\ker(\phi)} \to \phi(G)$ given by $g\ker(\phi) \to \phi(g)$ is an isomorphism. In symbols, $\frac{G}{\ker(\phi)} \approx \phi(G)$

Now, so far in the problems I've done, and the examples we did in class, $\phi(G) = \bar{G}$ has been used. As soon as I got to this problem though, this claim no longer seems to make sense. The kernel is non-trivial, so having $\frac{U(30)}{\{1,11\}} \approx U(30)$ makes no sense because the orders would not match up.

What I am hoping to confirm is how to find $\phi(G)$ because no examples were done in class nor in the book. I would also like to know when it is appropriate to take $\phi(G) = \bar{G}$ so that I avoid this confusion again.

It says the map is given by $g \ker(\phi) \to \phi(g)$. I suppose what I would do is find this map $\forall g \in G$. So, in $U(30) = \{1,7,11,13,17,19,23,29\}$, I would have

$\phi(1) = 1 * \{1,11\} = \{1,11\}$

$\phi(7) = 7 * \{1,11\} = \{7,77\} = \{7,17\}$

$\phi(11) = 11 * \{1,11\} = \{11,121\} = \{11,1\} = \phi(1)$

$\phi(13) = 13 * \{1,11\} = \{13,143\} = \{13,23\}$

$\phi(17) = 17 * \{1,11\} = \{17,187\} = \{17,7\} = \phi(7)$

$\phi(19) = 19 * \{1,11\} = \{19,209\} = \{19,29\}$

$\phi(23) = 23 * \{1,11\} = \{23,253\} = \{23,13\} = \phi(13)$

$\phi(29) = 29 * \{1,11\} = \{29,319\} = \{29,19\} = \phi(19)$

Then, $\phi(U(30)) = \{1,7,13,19\}$

Is this the correct process? If so, is there not an issue with the fact that the result is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4$ (i.e. isomorphic to a cyclic group)?

From here though, I could claim that $\phi$ is the following:

$\{1,11\} \to 1$

$\{7,17\} \to 7$

$\{13,23\} \to 13$

$\{19,29\} \to 19$

I am having a hard time believing this is indeed a homomorphism though. I feel like this maps to $\phi(U(30))$, not $U(30)$ itself. Can someone convince me that this is an homomorphism?

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: $\phi$ should go in the other direction, so that $\phi(11)=\phi(1)=1$.

Comment: @Shaun this is from Gallian, Contemporary Abstract Algebra

Comment: @Berci thank you for pointing that out. It was a small typo. I will update it

Comment: $U(30)$ is the group of units of the ring $\mathbb Z/30$.

Comment: @GEdgar We have not covered rings, sorry about that. Let me add that to clarify

Comment: My point was that a definition of the notation $U(30)$ should be included in the question!

Comment: @GEdgar I suppose there is perhaps multiple uses of that notation? I am unfamiliar with a second one. I did write U(30) later in the question, so I am going to leave it as is.

Comment: Can you use (or have you learned) the fact that every finite abelian group is isomorphic to some direct product of finite cyclic groups? (In particular, $U(30)$ has to be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_8$, $\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$, or $\mathbb{Z}_2^3$, and it's not hard to figure out which.)

Comment: @ConnorHarris yes I can, but I was told I don't even need the abelian assumption. I can just say that $U(n * m) \approx U(n) \oplus U(m)$ where $gcd(n,m) = 1$. In this case, I can write $U(30) \approx U(2) \oplus U(5) \oplus U(3) \approx \mathbb{Z}_1 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2} \approx \mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$. This is actually what I tried first believe it or not, but it didn't get me anywhere.

Comment: @NolanP here's a hint: write out an *explicit* isomorphism $\theta: \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \to U(30)$ such that $\theta(0, 0) = 1$ and $\theta(0, 1) = 11$. (You have a few possible values for $\theta(1, 0)$, but then the rest of $\theta$ is determined.) Then you can choose your homomorphism $\phi$ such that $\theta^{-1} \circ \phi \circ \theta$ is the projection map $(x, y) \mapsto (x, 0)$ (that is, $\phi$ "translates into" this projection map in $\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: Alternatively, can you use the fact that every homomorphism on $U(n)$ has the form $x \mapsto x^k$ for some fixed $k$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well we see that $\phi(7)=7\implies\phi(7^{2})=7^{2}$
So $\phi(19)=19$

Similarly $\phi(7^{3})=\phi(13)=13$.

So we know the images of $1,11,7,13,19$.

$\phi(11.7)=\phi(11).\phi(7)=7$

So $\phi(17)=7$. **(We are using the fact that $\phi(11)=1$ and $11.7=17)$**

again $\phi(11.19)=\phi(11)\phi(19)=19$.

So $\phi(29)=19$. **(We are using the fact that $\phi(11)=1$ and $11.19=29)$**

Again $\phi(11.13)=\phi(11)\phi(13)$

So $\phi(23)=13$.  **(We are using the fact that $\phi(11)=1$ and $11.13=23)$**

And you have your homomorphism

Namely $\phi$ is the homomorphism which takes

$1\to 1\,,7\to 7\,,11\to 1\,,13\to 13\,,17\to 7\,, 19\to 19\,, 23\to 13\,,29\to 19$

Also since all the information have been generated by the kernel and the known image of the element $7$ this is unique . Now we have to just basically check that this is indeed a homomorphism( it is obvious that it is....but for a complete proof we do have to just do the laborous task and verify it ). You can try and device a computer program for this. I tried to work on something like that once....but I could not finish it.

To answer to your question in the comments:-

you will see that for finite sets of same cardinality a surjection is a injection. So if $\phi(G)=\bar{G}$. You will have that $\phi$ is an isomorphism. In that case the kernel will be trivial. However when you are given that the kernel is non-trivial. Then you have to have that the inamge will only have as many elements as $|\frac{G}{\ker(\phi)}|$. Ofcourse I am only talking about finite groups.  So if we were to only use these concepts of First isomorphism Theorem I will argue like this:-

We are given that $\phi(7)=7$ and $\ker(\phi)=\{1,11\}$. So as $\frac{G}{\ker(\phi)}\cong \phi(G)$.

$\phi(G)$ can only have $4$ elements.

But since $\phi(7)=7$,$\phi(7^{2})=7^{2}$ , $\phi(7^{3})=7^{3}$ and $\phi(7^{4})=7^{4}$. We already have $4$ distinct elements.

So the images of the remaining elements must be one of the above $4$. We are given $\phi(11)=\phi(1)=1$. So we are left with $3$ other elements. Now the results have to be such that they agree with the facts $\phi(7)=7$ and $\phi(11)=1$. But as I showed above, the only way to have that is by the way I did . Hence we have our argument.

Comment: +1 For a clear answer assuming no more theory than necessary. One might want to verify that the map you have determined is indeed a homomorphism; this answer shows that *if* there is such a homomorphism then it must be this map. But a priori there may be no such homomorphism at all.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I verified uniqueness...but for existence part we do have to actually sit and verify that this is a homomorphism. I'll edit it.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron I agree that this answers the part of my question that this is indeed a homomorphism. I am satisfied with that. I also found that the comments from earlier verified that I found it correctly. Are you able to answer the remaining part? When is it sufficient to take $\phi(G) = \bar{G}$?

Comment: You don't have to have $\phi(G)=\bar{G}$ in order to use first isomorphism theorem. You can say that $\frac{G}{ker(\phi)}\cong \phi(G)$ where $\phi(G)$ is viewed as a subgroup of $\bar{G}$. You will see that this notion will be used several times in gallian. For example in Normalizer-Centralizer theorem. Or Cayley's theorem or even Generalized Cayley.

Comment: Also you will see that for finite sets a surjection is a injection. So if $\phi(G)=\bar{G}$. You will have that $\phi$ is an isomorphism. In that case the kernel will be trivial. However when you are given that the kernel is non-trivial. Then you have to have that the inamge will only have as many elements as $|\frac{G}{ker(\phi)}|$. Ofcourse I am only talking about finite groups.  Wait I'll edit in these parts.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron  I understand that I don't have to have $\phi(G) = \bar{G}$ to use the FIT. I am trying to find out when I am allowed to say that to avoid confusion. So are you saying that if G is finite, then having $\phi(G) = \bar{G}$ is an isomorphism? What if $|G| > |\bar{G}|$? Is it impossible to create a homomorphism then? I find that hard to. believe at the moment since homomorphisms don't need to preserve order.

Comment: Ah...no no ...finite and equal in size. Then you have Pigeon hole.  If $|G|\neq |\bar{G}|$ then there will not exist any bijection.  A homomorphism always exists from any two groups . That is the trivial homomorphism. So you can always find homomorphisms. For example you can have non-trivial homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z_{p}}$(In fact that is how you show $Z_{p}\cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p\mathbb{Z}}$ . But not in the reverse way. The only homomorphism from $Z_{p}\to\mathbb{Z}$ is just the trivial homomorphism. As all elements of $Z,+$ apart from $0$ has infinite order.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron maybe my question just isn't being asked well, but I'm still thoroughly confused. I am asking when can I take $\phi(G) = \bar{G}$? I know it is not true in general, but I want to do when I can do this.

Comment: Also forfetting about cardinality for a moment. You must satisfy the order criterions... order of phi(a) must divide order of (a). And there will be many more obstacles. It is indeed not very easy to just produce a epimorphism like that. While it is easy(well comparatively) for functions it is not at all easy epimorphisms. You have to be careful and verify that it is indeed a homomorphism and it is surjective. Also for example if phi is onto homomorphism then if G is commutative G' has to be commutative.

Comment: And then again you have that if phi is epimorphism and G is commutative then G' has to be commutative. So for example you cannot have an onto map from $Z_{8}$ to $D_{4}$. Even though they are of the same order. Infact you cannot have onto homomorphism from any commutative group to $D_{4}$. As dihedral group is not abelian. So you have to be careful while constructing such maps. It should not violate basic results about homomorphisms. But in my answer I just used the kernel and a fixed image of 7 to generate it. Hence it would not violate anything.

Comment: So to summarize you must have that the cardinality of G Should be greater than G'. And you must not vioate results about homomorphisms. The cardinality is a more subtle issue in infinite case. As you might know the interval (0,1) is equicardinal with real numbers even though it is a proper subset. But anyways...for finite sets...as long as order of domain is greater than equal to range . You will have a surjection.  But it has to also satisfy that it should be a homomorphism.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron Alright, I suppose I'm asking a bad question. It's a better idea for me to just take it as $\phi(G)$ and work from there. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: No no. Your question was a valid one and it wasn't one that was absolutely apparent. but the thing is that once you are familiar with properties functions(onto) from finite sets to finite sets and the properties of homomorphisms , they will become clearer on why such things are happening. I suggest you work with even smaller groups and try to find homomorphisms by hand. For example from $Z_{4}]to Z_{6}$. As you will solve them they will become clear and you will understand what is happening in the background of these homomorphisms.